# Past perfect or past simple + if

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions, past-perfect, if

Which one is more correct?

1. It is hard to say whether the more up-to-date file **had indeed been** on his desk before the meeting took place. **If it had been** he should be regarded as a liar.
2. It is hard to say whether the more up-to-date file **was indeed** on his desk before the meeting took place. **If it was** he should be regarded as a liar.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. But here it's just a matter of time frame: "had been vs was."

> had been - expresses the duration of the action ( it had been there [for/before some time] );
>
> was - on the other hand, is a simple tense ( it is not specified whether the action was ongoing);

Neither can be regarded as more or less correct. It mainly depends on the context, which in this case is perfectly fine.

I'll also say that "had indeed been" in the first sentence is preferable in case you want to order the sequence of actions and just that - it doesn't change the meaning itself.

I find this issue to be a question of writing style, so they are interchangeable.